# How I load js files on livewire component whent it's load

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

How I load js files on livewire components when the components load. I use like this on my livewire components bellow

```
@push('scripts')
<script src="{{url('/')}}/assets/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
@endpush
```

But it's not load when the component is loaded.

Comment: Do you have a `@stack('scripts')` in your layout file?

Comment: yes, but js loaded when I refresh the page, it's not loaded when I load livewire component event.

Comment: The application on local Server

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "load component event". It would help if you shared your code and better explain what is happening

Comment: I want to load js files when livewire component render.